# Why wrapping text is causing div box to move up?

Tags: html, css

What I wanted is actually to have 1 or at most 2 lines of text, if longer truncated with ellipsis. It didn't show and for some reason when it's more than 2 lines of text inside `.cell` div, then the box is jumping up.

```css
body {
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.row {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lime;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.cellDummy {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="row0">
    <div class="cellDummy" style="width: 740.5px;">boo</div>
    <div class="cell">1 ahsdjkha sdjha kshd kajhs dajhsdk</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

So the question is how to line up `.cell` boxes even with 2 line of text? How to make ellipsis if the text can't fit 2 lines(or some 10 percent of box's height)?

UPDATE
after changing vertical alignment now `.cellDummy` box jumps up.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the default vertical alignment of inline elements is `baseline`, which is what you're seeing. Try changing it to `top`:

```css
body {
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.row {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lime;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.cellDummy {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="row0">
    <div class="cellDummy" style="width: 740.5px;">boo</div>
    <div class="cell">1 ahsdjkha sdjha kshd kajhs dajhsdk</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To set the ellipsis you'd need to define the [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) and `overflow` properties.

Comment: For text ellipsis I guess I need inner div or span, which occupy fixed height in `.cell`?

Comment: You have a margin on your `.cell` divs that your .`cellDummy` doesn't have. And yes, you'd need to define a height for the ellipsis to kick in.

Comment: it works, just one last question - do I have to use span or another div solely to represent text inside `.cell` div, where also an image going to be residing?

Comment: No, I don't see any need to wrap your text in a span, div, or other element.